# How to concatenate leading zeros in excel

Tags: excel

I want to add  leading "0s" to every number:

```
0000 & 1 = 00001
```

But I need to count the length because the total number of characters shouldn't exceed 5, so if the number is 30 then then excel should show it as "00030".

If it's 100 then "00100".

I will then concatenate the following number onto the result: 1027, so, for 100, the end result would be 102700100.

Answer (score 37):

The following formula will format numbers so that they're padded with 0's up to 5 characters.

```
=TEXT(A1,"00000")
```

Comment: Excellent. Found this via google and it's simple and concise. +1

Answer (score 13):

You can use the formatting options in the `TEXT()` function. The syntax is `TEXT(value, format_text)`, so in your example you'd use a formula like:

`=TEXT(A1,"00000")`

To join the two numeric strings together

`=CONCATENATE("1027", TEXT(A1,"00000"))`

See: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/text-function-HP010062580.aspx

Comment: This method definitely worked the best for me. I was combining zip-codes with trailing text

Answer (score 7):

The [`right`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/right-rightb-functions-HP010342854.aspx) function will do what you want, if you put a bunch of zeroes before your number. If you want 5 digits total, you'd do something like this:

```
=right("00000" & 45, 5)
```

This would output `00045`.

If you are putting another number before it, you can just keep concatenating, like this:

```
=1027 & right("00000" & 45, 5)
```

You can, of course, replace any of those values with cell references to make it all more dynamic.